# Open link in mobile browser(safari) instead of Facebook native browser (html base)

Tags: html, facebook

Im developing a web with facebook share link function. I notice facebook mobile apps will open shared link in its own browser, instead of mobile broswer (IE. safari, chrome and so on). Is there any control on this able us to force facebook open the link in mobile browser?

Answer (score 3):

No.  The only reliable workaround is if you use the web app with an iOS app, and all users install that iOS app, you can send users to your iOS app to accomplish that task which isn't a great workaround.

An easier but still not optimal solution would be to detect the Facebook browser in the `user-agent` string, and display a message to prompt users to visit the URL in the mobile browser.

Comment: The ideal case for me is to open the link in web browser. I was thinking like detect user-agent, and if the console is facebook apps, i open a link in safari. is this possible?

Comment: This is not currently possible.

Comment: Is there any update on this ? Is still impossible today to force to open a link in the mobile browser instead of the facebook browser ?